# code is running fine line by line but fails when ran as a whole chunk in rmarkdown

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

When I run just this line of the code, the results are as expected. When I run the chunk, the mutations stop on the third line. How can I fix this, I feel like this is something new that I did not face before with the same code.

Sample data:

```
> dput(head(out))
structure(list(SectionCut = c("S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-2", 
"S-2"), OutputCase = c("LL-1", "LL-2", "LL-3", "LL-4", "LL-1", 
"LL-2"), V2 = c(81.782, 119.251, 119.924, 96.282, 72.503, 109.595
), M3 = c("-29.292000000000002", "-32.661999999999999", "-30.904", 
"-23.632999999999999", "29.619", "32.994"), id = c("./100-12-S01.xlsx", 
"./100-12-S01.xlsx", "./100-12-S01.xlsx", "./100-12-S01.xlsx", 
"./100-12-S01.xlsx", "./100-12-S01.xlsx")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
SectionCut = c("S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-2", "S-2"), 
OutputCase = c("LL-1", "LL-2", "LL-3", "LL-4", "LL-1", "LL-2"
), id = c("./100-12-S01.xlsx", "./100-12-S01.xlsx", "./100-12-S01.xlsx", 
"./100-12-S01.xlsx", "./100-12-S01.xlsx", "./100-12-S01.xlsx"
), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

> dput(head(Beamline_Shear))
structure(list(VLL = c(159.512186, 154.3336, 149.4451613, 167.0207595, 
161.2269091, 156.4116505)), row.names = c("84-9", "84-12", "84-15", 
"92-9", "92-12", "92-15"), class = "data.frame")
```

Code that I am trying to run:

```
Shear <- out[,-4] %>% mutate(N_l = str_extract(OutputCase,"\\d+"), 
                          UG = str_extract(id,"\\d+"), a = str_extract(id,"-\\d+"),
                          S = str_extract(a,"\\d+"), Sections = paste0(UG,"-",S),
                          Sample = str_remove_all(id, "./\\d+-\\d+-|.xlsx")) %>%
  left_join(Beamline_Shear %>% rownames_to_column("Sections"), by = "Sections") %>% 
  select(-OutputCase,-id,-Sections,-a)
```

Comment: It is working fine with the example though.  Can you show an example it doesn't work.  BTW, you can add `ungroup%>%` before the `mutate` step.   It may be possible that some attributes from group are messing the step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some group attributes in the data, which should work normally, but can be an issue if we are running in a different env.  Also, the `mutate` step and the join step doesn't really need any grouping attributes as they are fairly very straightforward rowwise operations that are vectorized.

```
library(dplyr)
out %>% 
    select(-4) %>%
    ungroup  %>% # // removes group attributes
    mutate(N_l = str_extract(OutputCase,"\\d+"), 
                           UG = str_extract(id,"\\d+"), a = str_extract(id,"-\\d+"),
                           S = str_extract(a,"\\d+"), Sections = paste0(UG,"-",S),
                           Sample = str_remove_all(id, "./\\d+-\\d+-|.xlsx")) %>% left_join(Beamline_Shear %>% rownames_to_column("Sections"), by = "Sections")
# A tibble: 6 x 11
#  SectionCut OutputCase    V2 id                N_l   UG    a     S     Sections Sample   VLL
#  <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <chr>             <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
#1 S-1        LL-1        81.8 ./100-12-S01.xlsx 1     100   -12   12    100-12   S01       NA
#2 S-1        LL-2       119.  ./100-12-S01.xlsx 2     100   -12   12    100-12   S01       NA
#3 S-1        LL-3       120.  ./100-12-S01.xlsx 3     100   -12   12    100-12   S01       NA
#4 S-1        LL-4        96.3 ./100-12-S01.xlsx 4     100   -12   12    100-12   S01       NA
#5 S-2        LL-1        72.5 ./100-12-S01.xlsx 1     100   -12   12    100-12   S01       NA
#6 S-2        LL-2       110.  ./100-12-S01.xlsx 2     100   -12   12    100-12   S01       NA
```